# Was Yajnesvara the only Indra in Svayambhuva Manvantara?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, indra, avatars, manvantara

In Srimad Bhagavatam (the treasure from which so many questions arise!), the story of Maharaja Prthu is described in the Fourth Canto, Chapters 15 to 23. In Chapters 19 and 20 is described the story of Prthu's 100 Ashvamedha Yajnas. According to this story, Prthu had performed 99 Yajnas, causing Indra to feel insecure about his position and that Prthu would usurp him. He then takes the garb of a fake sanyasi and steals the horse away. This causes a hullabaloo in Prthu's Yajnashala, and finally Lord Vishnu drags Indra to Prthu and seeks pardon on his behalf.

Later, in the 1st Chapter of the 8th Canto (Also referenced to in the 7th Chapter of the 2nd Canto), is the story of Lord Yajnesvara, the avatara of Vishnu, who due to lack of a proper authority, himself took up the post of Indra. He is described as the Indra of Svayambhuva.

If this is the case, then was it **Yajnesvara** who stole the horse and introduced to the world the practice of fake swamis? or was there an Indra who came later?

Or, did the story of Maharaja Prthu take place in Svarochisha Manu (which is highly unlikely)?

Comment: I think you'll strenuously object to this, but the Matsya Purana says "The rule of the king Prithu continued till the end of the Chakshusa Manvantara."  http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/23204/25F_Chapter_8.pdf I'm not sure what Manvantara Prithu was born in, though.

Comment: I don't know what to make of that. That would make him a tottering old man of 168,69,60,000 years. Approx 169 crore years. What would he be doing sitting on earth for so long though... no wonder the Bhagavatam describes him leaving the world with great happiness.

Comment: I don't think he necessarily lived that long.  He may have been born in a later Manvantara.

Comment: He was Dhruva's great grandson... so definitely he was born in Svayambhuva.

Comment: Well, one or more of his ancestors might have also lived across Manvantaras.

Comment: I have never seen this across Manvantaras thing for any other king... so what makes Svayambhuva Manu's descendants so special? Anyways, the point is did Yajnesvara - ohh, that's why this Manvantara problem is going on. To find out which Indra it was.

Comment: Yeah, if Prithu lived until the end of the Chakshusha Manvantara, it could have been Mantradruma/Ajagava who stole his horse.

Comment: But if it were so, surely Shukabrahmarshi would have mentioned it? During the course of the listing of Manus at least?

Comment: No, in the Puranas Vyasa doesn't really focus on incidents that were done by previous Indras.  In the listing of Manus, the only incidents Vyasa discusses are the stories of the Manvantara Avataras, like Hari son of Harita, Vamana, Yagna, etc.

Comment: Not the Indra thing. The fact that Prthu lived for 169 crore years.

Comment: Well, like I said I don't think it's necessarily true that he lived that long; he could have been born later.  In any case, in the listing of Manus Vyasa doesn't discuss the length of the rule of human kings at all.

Comment: Another interesting thing is Indra is referred to as Hari. And I think it is because here Hari means, the thief..

Comment: He is also referred to as Marutvan, which means the Marudganas were born already, which is coincidentally the previous chapter of the Matsya Purana chapter you linked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32213/discussion-between-surya-and-keshav-srinivasan).